# Как заполнить кругый блок текстом?

Tags: вёрстка

Здравствуйте, в интернете ничего не нашел по теме, как заполнить круглый блок текстом. К примеру:

> ```
> <div class="message">
>         <p class="message_autor"><strong>Заголовок</strong></p>
>         <div class="message_text">Много
> ```
>
> текстов

Ширина и высота блока одинковы, border-radius:50%, но текст в круг не встает, как добиться такого результата?

Сейчас выглядит так:

[image]

Хочу такой результат:

[image]

Может кто то знает как делается это?

Comment: с помощью SVG делаются оказывается такие вещи))

Comment: результат в студию!

Answer (score 1):

можно еще CSS Regions заюзать